# Global button cursor

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a way to set the default cursor for a control type at the application level? I'd like to say that all Button controls, regardless of whether or not they have a specific style, have a default cursor of the hand cursor unless it's overridden in that button's individual style specification.

Here's an example of such a button with its own style that I'd like to override the default

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CloseButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <!-- My button's custom content here -->
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Button x:Name="btnClose" Style="{DynamicResource CloseButtonStyle}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the style below in Application.Resources in your App.xaml file.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
</Style>
```

**UPDATE**

In regards to the 3rd comment:
To achieve that, you need to leave just your control template in `UserControl.Resources`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CloseButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Grid>
      <!-- My button's custom content here -->
   </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then set `Template` property for `Button`:

```
<Button Template="{DynamicResource CloseButtonTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for my buttons. I've edited my question with an example of a button that I've added a custom style that I'd like to have inherit the cursor value, in case it can provide insight to the solution.

Comment: If it doesn't work you may need to check your solution for default Buttons' style (such as in the answer). I mean that when you creating style without x:Key, just specifying the type - it works as a default style for the scope in which it defined. I've posted this answer after checking in temp project. You may check it yourself if you create temp solution, put in the MainWindow two buttons and specify the style from answer in your App.xaml.

Comment: Would you mind posting your temp solution's MainWindow code in the comments? I tried this with a temp 2 button solution as you suggested. A standard button, straight from the toolbox, works great with your example. A button with a template specified in the style, like what I posted above, still shows me no hand cursor when using a simple example of a rectangle in the control template.

Comment: Ah, using just a ControlTemplate instead of a Style that sets the ControlTemplate seems to be where my code was conflicting with your solution. It works now, thanks! Now all I have to do if figure out if I can do that in Expression Blend without too much extra work :)

Comment: Draw the control presentation in Blend and copy-paste xaml into your control template definition. It shouldn't introduce any extras. I'm glad that the answer helped you solve the problem.